# How to work around no output redirection in Windows powershell

Tags: python, powershell, cygwin

I have written a lot of code that relies on output redirection in cygwin.

I now have to integrate some libraries that aren't compatible with cygwin and that need in my case Windows or Linux.

Is there a smooth way to go from cygwin's `python script.py 42 <in.txt >out.txt` to powershell's equivalent? I know powershell can't use input/output redirection, at least not with the `<, >` (the documentation says it can weirdly) but is there another way?

Comment: FYI - PowerShell _does_ support *output* redirection.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell definitely can do input/output redirection, it just doesn't do it *the exact same way as bash*.

I'm assuming you don't want to actually learn PowerShell, just get a quick & dirty answer. So, here goes.

---

For simple cases, bash-like syntax works fine:

```
foo > out.txt
```

---

When that doesn't work, often just wrapping up the tool in Powershell scriptlet is all you need. In other words, create a `foo.ps1` file with this in it:

```
foo > out.txt
```

Then just run `foo.ps1` instead of `foo`.

---

You may also want to look at the `Tee-Object`, `Set-Content`, `Add-Content`, and `Start-Transcript`, etc. cmdlets. Start with [A Task-Based Guide to Windows PowerShell Cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332526.aspx).

For example, [`Start-Transcript`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849687.aspx) captures standard output as a "dumb string" and writes it to a file. So, one equivalent of `foo > out.txt` is:

```
Start-Transcript -path out.txt
foo
Stop-Transcript
```

Or, for `foo >> out.txt`:

```
Start-Transcript -path out.txt --append
foo
Stop-Transcript
```

Similarly, in the other direction, [`Get-Content`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176843.aspx) reads a text file and prints it out as a dumb string, which you can pipe to your program:

```
Get-Content in.txt | foo
```

---

Of course another obvious possibility is to change your Python script to take filenames.

In many cases, just using [`fileinput.input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) instead of `sys.stdin` gives you this for free—you can pass it a file's content via stdin, or a filename on the command line (or all kinds of fancier combinations) and the script will see it the same way.